# Images (e.g. with Clonezilla) of Windows and Linux on a UEFI computer

Tags: windows, images, uefi, clonezilla

I use Clonezilla with success for many years to make images from partitions that host Windows 7 or smaller and Ubuntu and other operating systems. Making images and restore them was easy for me.

But now with the advent of UEFI I‘m not sure how to make images with Clonezilla and how to restore them in a correct way.

I am running Windows 7 and Ubuntu on the same GPT disk. Both using UEFI.

**The questions are**:

- If a want to make a restoreable image of the partition hosting Windows 7 or 8 with Clonezilla, do I have to make also an image of the „EFI System partition“ and the MRP?
- Or is it not required to make images of the partitions „EFI System partition“ and MRP, because it is possible to rebuild these both partitions (maybe with a Windows installation disc or with an Linux tool) after restoring the images of Windows and Ubuntu on a new disk?
- What is a easy way to restore an Windows 7 or 8 (UEFI) image on a new disk - do I have to create the other partitions („EFI System partition“ and MRP) manually before restoring the image?

I know that it is possible to clone the hole disk and not only one single partition, but this is not what I want.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you did it *right* you would centralize *all* boot related files for *all* installed operating systems on a single esp - that's the point of the esp. And so your separate os images could be boot agnostic, and you could then just keep a single backup image of your machine's entire boot platform.

Comment: Several ESPs are fine in practice (but all of them should be backed up then unless one wants to know a little bit more at restore time which is usually undesirable) -- I'd rather worry about either NVRAM EFI variables or getting some fallback bootloader in place (that it /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi that probably contains a bootmanager like Refind or shim); Rod's books are generally recommended: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html